# How to embed HTML in SuccessMessageMixin?

Tags: python, django, message

How do I embed html code here. I tried using mark_safe, it didn't work

```
class PostCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'blogApp/create.html'
    success_url = '/'
    success_message = mark_safe(
        '<strong>%(title)s</strong> Created Successfully')
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
success_message = "<h1>hello</h1>"
```

Now in your html, where you are rendering messages

put a safe filter like this:

```
{{message|safe}}
```

Comment: haah I was so obsessed using that in views that I totally forgot I can filter it in templates lol